# Strange linkage error when using friend method

Tags: c++

main.cpp

```
#include "test.cpp"

int main()
{

}
```

test.cpp

```
// test.cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Test
{
public:
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, Test& o1);
};


ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, Test& c)
{
    return out;
}
```

Output:
***Error 1***: Severity Code    Description Project File    Line    Column  Suppression State
Error   LNK2005 "class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits > & __cdecl operator<<(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits > &,class Test &)" (??6@YAAAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@AAV01@AAVTest@@@Z) already defined in crops.obj   Test    E:\Desktop\University\Programming\C++\KPI\Test\Test\main.obj
***Error 2***: Severity Code    Description Project File    Line    Column  Suppression State
Error   LNK1169 one or more multiply defined symbols found  Test    E:\Desktop\University\Programming\C++\KPI\Test\Debug\Test.exe   1   1

Why I have two linkage errors? What coul d be wrong there?

Comment: Never include `.cpp`-files. How do you compile?

Comment: Offtopic: `const` is missing: `ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Test& c)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Error message is descriptive there, you are redefining the operator. That happen because you are trying to link objects that contains the same definition.
The problem here is that you are including the "test.cpp" and you are probably compiling it (and then trying to link).

You should include only files containing declarations (typically .h), you should create something like this:

```
//test.h
//declarations and inline methods only here
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Test
{
public:
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, Test& o1);
};


ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, Test& c);
```

```
//test.cpp
//definitions here
#include "test.h"
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, Test& c)
{
    return out;
}
```

```
//main.cpp
#include "test.h"

int main()
{

}
```

Then compile test.cpp, main.cpp and link the two together.

Comment: You should never place a `using namespace` and especially not `using namespace std;` in a header file.